# Get interest area of a Histogram (Int Array)

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, pattern-matching, histogram

I have an int array full of values (0-255) and I need to extract two indexes.

The indexes to be found will represent the Interesting Area  I want to focus on.

The values of this area are **always** higher than the others but sometimes the difference is very low.

Like this example:

[image]

My interest area is this:

[image]

My current approach is to get the Max value and Average value.  Then I will get:

- the first index greater than "Max - (Max - Average)".
- the last index greater than "Max - (Max - Average)".

But sometimes, like in this case my method gets the Junk part. (The fifth "column", on the right)

Anyone can suggest a better approach?

Note:
The interest area has always 4 "columns" like the example image

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a simple Impulse Response Filter such as Boxcar or any other means of smoothing to your histogram to reduce the high frequency components. After that you could calculate the local minima and maxima and pin-point the individual peaks (max-min-max-min per peak) within a bandwidth which would help to narrow down the ROI.

Here is a simple [Boxcar](https://github.com/rennhak/Keyposes/blob/master/src/BodyComponents/Filter.rb#L247) filter implementation of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm assuming too much. But your data makes it look like there are strong 'edges' around the 4 'mountains'. So you should look at those [edge/ridge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) group of algorithms for idea.

My simplest answer would be to try thresholding first. see if that works.

If not, maybe applying one-dimensional version of filter such as [Sobel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).
They should highlight the important points in your data where second order derivative is large.